# cakephp - how to redirect in a Component

Tags: cakephp, components

I created a Component and in this component I try to redirect to a different controller/action, but I get the error: "`Error: Call to undefined method SessionRestComponent::redirect()`"

My Component code:

```
function iniciaSessao($username=''){
                 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                                //  debug(isset($_SESSION['username']));
                                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'registos', 'action' => 'indexUser'));
                                }
            }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the controller - for example in initialize() or startup()
Then redirect using this controller.

```
public function startup(Controller $controller) {
    $this->Controller = $controller;
}

public function iniciaSessao() {
    ...
    $this->Controller->redirect($url);
}
```

and do not use $_SESSION directly, use $this->Session component as documented.
You just need to add the component to your custom component:

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

Comment: thank you mark.

but when you say '$this->Controller->redirect($url);'... i use $this->Users->redirect('index')? (for example)


i'm sorry but i dont understand.

Comment: No i mean exactly what i wrote. literally. A component usually should not need to know the exact controller its working on. its the other way around.

Comment: but i dont understand how use the code. :/

i used this    $this->Controller->redirect('UsersController/login');  and i have the same error.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Cakephp 3 here's [a link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#accessing-a-component-s-controller). Where inside the component

```
function iniciaSessao($username=''){
     ...
     $this->_registry->getController()->redirect($url);
}
```